# verifyIdToken function to validate id_token is failing upon invalid id_token

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

Following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth), I'm trying to make a function on the server that verifies the id_token and then returns a "true" if it was successfully verified or "false" if it's an invalid token.

Currently when it verifies a legitimate id_token there are no problems, but when I give it a fake one to test I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) error.

As my function failed I pared it back in order to make it closer to the [API instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).

I'm using PHP Version 7.3.7

```
var id_token = auth2.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token;
if (typeof id_token == 'undefined') {
    id_token = "XYZ123"; //dummy id_token if they're not logged in
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'submit.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
};
xhr.send('id_token=' + id_token + '&q=' + textToSend);
```

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$id_token = $_POST["id_token"];

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
    echo $payload['sub'];
} else {
    // Invalid ID token
}
```

I'm not necessarily looking for someone to write my function for me, but when my code is virtually identical to the instructions I'm looking to explain why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Have you checked the error log for more information about what's happening? Without anything more than "500 error" there's not much we can help with.

Comment: the user interface for my web hosting has changed and I can't find the error log so I think this will just have to sit as it is for now

Comment: Put a try/catch around `$client->verifyIdToken`. This will catch errors and prevent the 500 error.